# Selenium 3 firefox is not going to the given url

Tags: webdriver, navigatetourl, geckodriver, selenium3

I'm new with using Java, Selenium en the Webdriver

I use: selenium 3 beta3, Java jdk1.8.0_101 and firefox 48.01
Also I use the Geckodriver because that is needed for working with sel3.

I am trying to open a url. Opening the browser is working. 
The code I use is below.

```
package AutomatedScripts;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; // driver for Webdriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; //driver for Firefox

public class GoogleSearchOneTime {

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\selenium-3.0.0\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        // Launch a firefox browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // go to Google.com
        driver.get("http://www.google.com"); 
        // go to google.com
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");           

        //Enter search terms
        //driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
        //driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Google");

        //Click on the searh button
        //driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
        //check page title contacts the search term


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace you System.setProperty as below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\selenium-3.0.0\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Here an example link that you can refer [Launching firefox browser using Geckodriver](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3)